# how to pass textbox value to @html.hidden() to go to my controller MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

how to pass textbox value to @html.hidden() to go to my controller MVC
which my view is :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Reject", "Maker", FormMethod.Get))
{
 <div class="filed">
 <form class="RejectForm">
  <p> <input type="text" class="RejectTextBox" name="HidField" id="HidField" value="" placeholder="سبب الرفض"> 
  @Html.ValidationMessage("_strRejectReason", new { @style = "color:red" })</p>
  <br />

  <input id="RejectButton" type="submit" value="Reject"/>                                           
  </form>
  </div>

 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model._strRejectReason, new { id = "HidField"})
 @Html.Hidden("id", item.Id);
 <p>@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError", new { @style = "color:red" })</p>
 }
```

the Problem is my controller receives an empty object of the model which is the model contain
two properties int id ,string _strRejectReason which i send them using @Html.Hidden(); but the model object in controller  as paramter is empty my controller is :

```
public ActionResult Reject(MakerTransactions MakerTransactions)
    {
        MakerCheckerUnitOfWorkBase _MakerCheckerUnitOfWorkBase = new MakerCheckerUnitOfWorkBase();
        MakerTransactions.RouteAgentsConfigsMaker = _MakerCheckerUnitOfWorkBase.RouteAgentsConfigsChecker.RejectMaker(MakerTransactions.id,MakerTransactions._strRejectReason);

        return View(MakerTransactions);
    }
```

Comment: MVC use property name and not Id

Comment: Are you trying to set the value of hidden field by the content of text box when you submit? Then you do not need to submit the whole form you can use click event of button(change submit type to button) to set the hidden value from textbox content, else you can directly use Request["HidField"] to get value of the text box or take it in a model.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Reject", "Maker", FormMethod.Get))
{
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model._strRejectReason)
 @Html.Hidden("id", item.Id);
 <p>@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError", new { @style = "color:red" })</p>
 }
```

MVC use Name from tags. Then when you add a tag Id with a different name the server doesn't recognise this property.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model._strRejectReasonm, new {id = "sample" })

public ActionResult Reject(FormCollection collection)
    {
        var _strRejectReason = collection["_strRejectReason"];
        var id = collection["id"];
        return View();
    }
```